# Passing in single quote into function REPLACE gives error. How can I achieve this?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Column named : Body in table of Data Type - Text
Sample data contains HTML tags and hyper links. The hyperlinks use a single quote.

When I am trying to replace the single quote with a double quote using the T-SQL function below :

```
REPLACE(Body, '''', '"')
```

gives me the error indicated below--->

Argument data type text is invalid for argument 1 of replace function.

Question : Can you tell me  how I can pass a HTML formatted column in T-SQL containing single quotes in hyperlinks into a REPLACE function ?

This worked : Select REPLACE(CAST(Body as varchar(max)), '''', '"') as Bdy  FROM TABLE

I tried writing a function( code given below):

```
DECLARE @Temp VARCHAR(MAX)   
Set @Temp = THIS CONTAINS THE HTML FORMATTED TEXT WITH HYPERLINK IN SINGLE QUOTE'; 
Set @Temp = REPLACE(@Temp , '''', '"')   
Select @Temp;
```

And the function fails indicating

`Incorrect syntax near '/'.`

Comment: you should be using varchar(max) not TEXT as column datatype

Comment: I am using varchar(max) in the function I am doing the replace but the column has a datatype TEXT.

Comment: you need to make sure any single quotes in your string literal are escaped by doubling them up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit based on your comment: have you tried casting `text` to `varchar` ?  Like:

```
REPLACE(cast(Body as varchar(max)), '''', '"')
```

Old answer: in SQL, a single quote is escaped by another single quote.  So you should do:

```
REPLACE(Body, '''', '"')
```

That's four single quotes, comma, single qoute, double quote, single quote.

Comment: I am already escaping the single quote with another single quote which is 4 single quotes. The issue is that when I pass in the data column BODY which cotains HTML formatted hyperlinks which contain single quotes. I get that error message I indicated.

Comment: DECLARE @Temp VARCHAR(MAX) Set @Temp = 'test<br><br>Related Links<br><a href='http://www.xxx.com'/>link name</a><br>'; Set @Temp = REPLACE(@Temp , '''', '"') Select @Temp;

Comment: @Ruruboy: The appplication generating that has to escape the single quotes, otherwise it sends badly formed SQL to the database server.

Comment: @Andomar: Escaping the single quotes is being done at the database level. A stored procedure passes in the column to the function. Meaning the function is called from the stored procedure. I would think that if I cast the column name to varchar(max) and pass it into the function that does the REPLACE it should work. lets wait and see.

Comment: I just wanted to let you know that it worked, when I CAST and passed it as a parameter into the Function. I did this at the database level though from the stored procedure that called this function. I will mark your answer right for the CAST.